# How can I add keyboard shortcuts and mappings to OS X (for example: I'd like Ctrl-u and Ctrl-i to map to [ and ], respectively)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been playing with the idea of mapping all of the keys to the right of the P in a QWERTY keyboard to some kind of modifier key, preferably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on my Mac.

Looking around, I haven't found a good way to do that. Would love any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this task (and other remapping even with makro support) I recommend using Ukelele which is a Unicode Keyboard Layout Editor for the macOS.
Yo define your own keyboard layout and just use it via the system -> keyboard layout chooser.
[Ukelele is freeware](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) and more details can be found on the download page

Comment: This looks perfect. Thank you!